# PowerApps "Time without date" control hour offset

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I'm working with a datetime field in my model-driven PowerApp (UCI). I'm trying to set the value to the current time using Javascript like
`Xrm.Page.getAttribute("starttime").setValue(new Date())`

With the default control I get:
[image]
which is the correct time and expected but when I switch to the "Time without date" control and run the same JS, I get:
[image]

which seems to be an offset by 1 hour. I don't know why the control changes the behavior - is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
My field is marked as time zone independent.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the case in my test environment and there is no issue with Time only control.
below are the actions taken:

1. defined two new DateTime fields on the contact entity, The behavior of the two fields
   is Time-Zone Independent
2. Add the control "Time without Date" for the second date field on the contact form.
3. After publishing the customizations set both fields value by executing the below two
   commands on chrome console
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_mkdatewithoutc").setValue(new Date())
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_mkdatewithc").setValue(new Date())
4. Both Fields have the same time as appeared in the below screenshot

[image]